MacOS Runners Fail Due to Missing Dependencies in Cached venv on GitHub Actions
I'm encountering a peculiar issue with GitHub Actions in a large project where the success of macOS runner jobs seems to hinge on the order in which they're executed. Specifically, jobs that depend on a cached Python virtual environment (venv) sometimes fail because, upon loading, the venv appears to lack previously installed dependencies. This problem only manifests on macOS runners; Linux runners are unaffected.
Setup Details:

Python project: Using pip for installation.
Configuration File: The project is configured using pyproject.toml.
CI/CD: GitHub Actions, utilizing the cache action to store and retrieve the venv.
Project Size: Large, with some dependencies requiring significant time to build from scratch.
Minimal example: https://github.com/JakobEliasWagner/ci-fail
Failed job: https://github.com/JakobEliasWagner/ci-fail/actions/runs/8538759996/job/23392158256

Observed Behavior:

When running multiple jobs in a certain sequence, some jobs on macOS runners fail.
Failure Point: Jobs fail due to an inability to locate dependencies that should have been installed and cached in the venv during previous runs.
Reproducibility: Running the jobs multiple times reproduces this issue for this minimal example. Inside a much bigger project this manifests almost every time. Jobs that fail are at random (but always MacOS).
Minimal example: https://github.com/JakobEliasWagner/ci-fail
Failed job: https://github.com/JakobEliasWagner/ci-fail/actions/runs/8538759996/job/23392158256

Attempted Steps:

Initial setup works for all jobs.
Deleted caches and rebuilt cache multiple times.
Changed the order of different jobs.
Reproducible in minimal example.

Questions:

Are there know limitations to using caching in github?
What is the best way to solve this while minimizing runtimes of individual runners?
Any recommendations on alternative caching strategies or configurations.

Any insights or suggestions from those who've navigated similar challenges would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  run_main:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: ["ubuntu-latest", "macos-latest"]
        python-version: ["3.9", "3.10", "3.11"]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Cache ID
        shell: bash
        run: |
          RAW_ID="${{ matrix.os }}-${{ matrix.python-version }}-venv-${{ hashFiles('pyproject.toml') }}"
          PROCESSED_ID=$(echo $RAW_ID | tr -d '[],')
          echo "CACHE_ID=$PROCESSED_ID" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Cache venv
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        id: cache-venv
        with:
          path: .venv
          key: ${{ env.CACHE_ID }}
      - name: Setup venv
        shell: bash
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m venv .venv
          . ./.venv/bin/activate
          pip install .
        if: steps.cache-venv.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      - name: Activate venv
        shell: bash
        run: |
          source .venv/bin/activate
          echo "VIRTUAL_ENV=${VIRTUAL_ENV}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      - name: List dependencies
        shell: bash
        run: |
          python -m pip list
      - name: Run file
        run: |
          which python
          python main.py

  run_main_twice:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: ["ubuntu-latest", "macos-latest"]
        python-version: ["3.9", "3.10", "3.11"]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Cache ID
        shell: bash
        run: |
          RAW_ID="${{ matrix.os }}-${{ matrix.python-version }}-venv-${{ hashFiles('pyproject.toml') }}"
          PROCESSED_ID=$(echo $RAW_ID | tr -d '[],')
          echo "CACHE_ID=$PROCESSED_ID" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Cache venv
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        id: cache-venv
        with:
          path: .venv
          key: ${{ env.CACHE_ID }}
      - name: Setup venv
        shell: bash
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m venv .venv
          . ./.venv/bin/activate
          pip install .
        if: steps.cache-venv.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      - name: Activate venv
        shell: bash
        run: |
          source .venv/bin/activate
          echo "VIRTUAL_ENV=${VIRTUAL_ENV}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      - name: List dependencies
        shell: bash
        run: |
          python -m pip list
      - name: Run file
        run: |
          which python
          python main.py
      - name: Run file
        run: |
          which python
          python main.py

